# Using visual c++ tools for windows desktop with installer

Tags: c++, installation, setup-deployment

I used these tools to allow me to build a C++ project that was part of an expert system tutorial (CLIPSCLRWrapper), and that worked fine. My question is how do I include the dependencies in an installation of my final executable so that it can be installed on a clean system, without Visual Studio?

I'm using the above wrapper DLL in a C# Windows forms application, then making an installer for the resulting executable, but it seems to be missing some dependencies when I install on another PC without Visual Studio. How can I discover which dependencies are missing that are provided by the tools for windows desktop, and how do I add them to my installer?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies can be added to the installer, by adding them to "Application Folder". First, open "File System" of the installer, then you will find sub folders one of them called "Application Folder". Inside the "Application Folder", you could put all the application dependencies.

Good luck